# Why do I get an inferred latch error here?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I've been building a design in the simulator that uses a shift register. It has the following design goals:

- if `reset_i`, then set `pout_o` to zero.
- if `load_i`, then set `pout_o` to `pin_i`.
- if `sclk_i`, shift out one bit.

The HDL is:

```
module ShiftRegister #(parameter N = 8)
(
    input logic sclk_i,
    input logic reset_i,
    input logic load_i,
    input logic d_i,
    output logic q_o,
    input logic [N-1:0] pin_i,
    output logic [N-1:0] pout_o
);

always @(posedge sclk_i or posedge reset_i or posedge load_i) begin
    if(reset_i) pout_o <= 0;
    else if(load_i) pout_o <= pin_i;
    else begin
        q_o <= pout_o[N-1];
        pout_o <= {pout_o[N-2:0], d_i};
    end
end

endmodule
```

I'm getting an error saying "Latch inferred for net pout_o", and my design is not working as intended. `pout_o` will retain the value of `pin_i` at all times, never saving it. This is critical to the design and I'm not sure how else to achieve this. What can I do to fix this?

Edit: This design works as intended in the simulator.

Comment: Why do you want (posedge load)? ... That's not going to be synthesised as seen in the simulation.

Comment: The main clock for the design is much faster than the shift clock. I want to be able to load data into the shift register independently of it.

Comment: `if(load_i) pout_o <= pin_i;` is what a latch does, yes. A register of the type FPGAs like would only load on the rising edge of sclk_i, even if load_i was high.

Comment: So a better approach might be to combine the sclk and load signals I guess so that the process is always triggered?

Comment: Assuming `load_i` is synchronous to `sclk_i` then all you need to do is remove the `or posedge load_i` bit and you should be good. Whenever `sclk_i` rises the block will detect whether `load_i` is high and act accordingly.

Comment: @DarrenAnderson FPGA registers typically have one clock (each) and do not load independently of it. You should probably get load_i and pin_i to be not-independent of s_clk

Comment: They no longer are independent of sclk, and the problem is solved. Thank you @user253751

Comment: But it won't synthesise as you expect it to be because you are clocking a register with two clocks (load, sclk) while registers can can have only one clock in FPGAs

Comment: What I've done is add an extra clock every time I want to load a new value, seems to work okay.

Comment: It won't work on board. It will work only on simulation. You have to use load as clock enable on sclk, to make this work on an actual board. This is a case of synthesis-simulation mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to "why" here, but in general you should make the always block be sensitive to the system clock.  Then, inside the module logic, you should detect the rising edge of your shift clock by synthesizing a one-clock-wide signal.

My HDL is rusty enough I'll just get it wrong if I tried, but the *action* you're looking for is:

- last_sclk_i <= sclk_i
- rising_sclk_i <= sclk_i and not last_sclk_i
- if reset, set everything to zero (synchronous with the system clock).  You don't need to detect the rising edge of reset; this can just happen over and over again.
- else if load, set everything to the load value (synchronous with the system clock).  Here again, you don't need to detect the rising edge.
- else if rising_sclk_i, shift.